# Error : An error occurred while installing Unyson: Could not create directory. /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/unyson/

Tags: wordpress

I have Woffice theme, due to too many redirects, I deactivated all plugins including woffice core plugins. Now I try to reactivate plugins, there is issue occur.

> An error occurred while installing Unyson: 
>   Could not create directory.
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/unyson/.

I have AWS server. Please answer it

Comment: This is permission issue , make sure have write permission on your server . if no then enable it it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute this command?

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins
```

Here you can find the full reference of the permissions in Bitnami WordPress:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/#permissions-and-ownership

Comment: Thanks. I got it . I don't have access for it

Comment: your welcome bro , can you please approve answer if it worked

Comment: Yes its work, but still the issue is that. Some plugins work with that. But still main plugins are not acti9vated, and the same error occurs. ON Bitnami, Error; Plugins not found